# Marca este error con el pickle en Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, android, python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este problema al correr mi script recalco que estoy utilizando la 2.7 de python, quisiera ver si me pueda ayudar

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que mencionas? ¿Será que no has importado el módulo `pickle`?

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta cambiando la imagen por el código?

Comment: En vez de seleccionar el código, ¿podrías mostrar el error por consola? Saludos.

Comment: Porque las etiquetas "android" y "javascript", te sugiero editar tu pregunta , revisa [ask], saludos.